# Importing moment into Angular gives error

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am getting following error: `Module '".../node_modules/moment/moment"' has no exported member 'default'`when I use

`import * as _moment from 'moment';
import { default as _rollupMoment } from 'moment';
const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;`

Answer (score 4):

From Moment's Docs:

*Note: If you have trouble importing moment, try adding 
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in compilerOptions 
in your tsconfig.json file and then use the syntax*

Answer (score 2):

That's because `moment` does not have something called `default` did you mean `defaultFormat`?

Also you don't need your second import. You can just say `_moment.defaultFormat`

Answer (score 2):

I had so much trouble with trying to properly import Moment that I switched to the [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) library instead.

date-fns takes a somewhat different approach - as the name implies, it's a collection of date functions, rather than a huge 'god object' that does everything.

The additional benefits are that a) you can import just the individual functions that you need, and b) if you import the whole thing, it tree-shakes really well. So you wind up with a much smaller impact on your module size.