# How to use moment.js from cdns in Angular App

Tags: angular, momentjs

I am trying to follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51534969) to include `moment.js` from `CDNs` in Angular Component but throwing error `_moment is not defined`.

**Index.html**

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

**Component**

```js
import * as _moment from 'moment'; // works well but includes in main.js bundle on ng build --prod
// declare let _moment: any; // throws error '_moment is not defined' but not included in main.js as expected to use from CDNs
    
ngOnInit(): void {
    const d = _moment(value).format('DD-MMM-YY');
    console.error(d);
}
```

I tried both in `online` and `off-line` but no luck.

Note: I ran `npm i moment --save-dev` to use moment in `dev` environment where internet is not available.

**Angular.json**

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
]
```

I am using Angular 10. Did I miss something?

Comment: can you share your full code of angular.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top of your component type:

```
declare let moment: any; //declare moment
```

And you're got to go (leave the script imports in index.html). Down-side of this solution is that you're missing intelligence and everything you love in typescript ;)

Comment: throws error `_moment is not defined` but not included in `main.js` as expected to use from `CDNs`

Comment: remove the underscore

Comment: In case you import moment like from an npm package, you reference moment using a variable name you can make up, like _moment. If you use the package from CDN, you'll have to deal with the name in the library

Answer (score 0):

please try
[npm i moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

```
import * as _moment from 'moment';
```

Note: If you have trouble importing moment, try adding "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true in compilerOptions in your tsconfig.json file and then use the syntax[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54364974/7469332)

Comment: works well but includes in `main.js` bundle on `ng build --prod` for which I want my app to use `moment` from `CDNs`